# Update existing table with new user list than running entire query to replace table everyday?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running query in a job that updates user list everyday in SQL Server.
The query below is running everyday to update the data

```
if object_id('report.dbo.data') is not null    
drop table report.dbo.data
 SELECT
 UserID,
date
into report.dbo.data
 from data a
 where date >= '2019-01-01'
 and date < getdate()
```

The objective of this query is to update a user list everyday. Problem here is that, running it everyday takes longer time.

For example, I might already have data till 04/20/2019. Since I run it everyday, data runs once again from 01/01/2019 till 04/25/2019 rather than just updating with new userIDs from 04/20/2019 - 04/25/2019.

Can you help me with a sample code that updates `report.dbo.data` with new data than running entire code to refresh all data?

Comment: If you want instant updates, switch to a trigger based solution.

Comment: Drop the job and create a trigger on table data that inserts into report.dbo.data. Its not only faster, but is always 100% up to date, at any given time not just once a day

Answer (score 1):

Your code drops and recreates the whole table, not only data (contents) of it. Let's create an empty table `report.dbo.data`, if it doesn't exist and append new data only.

```
if object_id('report.dbo.data') is null
    SELECT UserID, date into report.dbo.data from data a where 1=0  -- create empty table if needed

insert into report.dbo.data(UserID, date)     -- append new data
    (SELECT UserID, date from data a where date > (select max(date) from data) and date < getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding date as  `'2019-01-01'` pass `max(date) from data`.

```
Insert into  report.dbo.data
SELECT UserID, date from data a where date >= (select max(date) from data ) and date < getdate()
```